# Import css3/compass from Angular Typescript

Tags: css, angular, typescript, sass, compass

I tried to use `compass` from an Angular application written in TypeScript (not Javascript), but when I write the next line:

```
// general.scss
@import 'compass/css3';
```

I get the following error:

```
@import 'compass/css3';
^
      File to import not found or unreadable: compass/css3.
```

How could I install compass?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try importing it with this `~` as in (if you've installed compass-mixins),

```
@import '~compass-mixins/lib/compass/css3';
```

Comment: have you installed compass (or compass-mixins)? what package do you have in your `node_modules` folder?

Comment: I installed compass: npm install compass.

Comment: And now I installed compass-mixins as well with the same result :'(

Comment: Updated my answer based on compass-mixins.

Comment: Hi, I wonder the `~` indicates that find this module from `node_modules`. Am I right?

Answer (score 6):

Thanks good I found the solution. Simply install compass-mixins:

```
$ npm install compass-mixins
```

And then read it from the node_modules folder:

```
@import '../../../node_modules/compass-mixins/lib/compass';
```

It's a bit cumbersome, but it works.

**update:** Do not use the previous import. Use the following syntax, as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/47932124/1704895

```
@import '~compass-mixins/lib/compass/css3';
```

Answer (score -2):

Indeed below one worked for me.

@import '//classpath:compass/css3';